# How to print all words in an array and split them in the same function

Tags: c, pointers

I have a program like this to print all the words in
the word_array, with delimit separating the words, and a \n after the
last word.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<assert.h>
void capitalize(char * lowercase) {
    while (*lowercase) {
        *lowercase = toupper(*lowercase) ;
        lowercase++ ;
    }
    return ;
}

void capitalize_all(char ** string) {
    while (*string) {
        capitalize(*string) ;
        string++ ;
    }
    return ;
}
void print_everything(char ** string, char * delimiter) {
    scanf("string =",string) ;
    for(int i=0; sp[i]!='\0'; i++)
   {
      printf("%c", string[i]);

      if(*string[i]==' ')
      {
         printf("\n");
      }
   }
    return ;
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int char ;
    char ** the_word_array ;
    char ** pp ;
    int i ;
    while ((char = getopt(argc, argv, "")) != -1) {
        switch(char) {
            break ;
        default:
                printf("%s\n", USAGE_MESSAGE) ;
                return 0 ;
        }
    }
    argc -= optind; // these are globals defined in the getopt code
    argv += optind;

    the_word_array = (char **) malloc((sizeof(void *)*(argc+1))) ;
    for (i=0;i<argc;i++) {
        the_word_array[i] = argv[i] ;
    }
    the_word_array[argc] = NULL ;
    pp = the_word_array ;
    capitalize_all(pp) ;
    print_all(word_array," ") ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

and I want to print everything words in the array + using delimiter to separate the words, and a \n after the last word in the print_everything function. How to do that?

Comment: just use `strtok` . See [strtok() and strtok_r() functions in C with examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strtok-strtok_r-functions-c-examples/)

Comment: I know, but there will be pointer issue if we use it inproperly.

Comment: Yes. So what is the problem? Try and if it does have problems ask about them here.

Comment: If we use delimit in the link above the program will not run, and I will have an error like this:
error: passing argument 1 of 'strtok' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|

Comment: `from incompatible pointer type` is a warning not error! You must check pointer to be not null after `strtok`. Ofcourse you must pass char * to `strtok`

Comment: That's not a program, that's just 3 functions.

Comment: The question is unclear.  Why are you writing into `string` in the `print_everything` function?  Do you really expected input to match `string = ...`?  Are you hoping to split the inputs on the single character `delimeter[0]`, or do you want to match an string, or do you want to match a regex?  Show some sample input with desired output, and include a complete program that readers can compile and execute (eg, with a main function)

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do the thing that Pursell said. The output I would like to have looks like this: "Hello\n" "the\n" World\n". Also I have updated my code.

Comment: That's not your program. It has a syntax error in it. Please provide the actual program that you've compiled.

Comment: That's the actual program.

Comment: What "thing that Pursell said"?  There are (at least) 3 reasonable ways to use `delimeter`, and I do not know which one you want.

Comment: I'm just trying to to complete the print_all routine to print all the words in
the word_array, with delimit separating the words, and a \n after the 
last word. You know